# Не работает видео из YouTube в Android

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

Вроде все сделал, как написано в https://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-youtube-api-to-embed-video-in-an-android-app/, но при запуске вылетает, как это исправить?

```
public class ContestsDetals extends AppCompatActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    private String url = "https://adftegcb.com/api/contestspets?id=9&token=$1$vLyWeNSm$tMhTzT5N7KKu4nznlCZ1Q.&number=";
    private String TAG = ContestsView.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String idUrl = "";
    private String title = "Contest view";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
    private ListView lv;
    private ListView lv2;

    public static final String YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyABW6E8tWmZvMgDspTHlOMdb6zmqETC4kk";
    private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contests_detals);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        new ContestsDetals.GetContacts().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo("fhWaJi1Hsfo"); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    protected Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return youTubeView;
    }


    public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            setTitle(title);
            // here you let SimpleAdapter built the view normally.
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            // Then we get reference for Picasso
            ImageView img = (ImageView) v.getTag();
            if (img == null) {
                img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivBasicImage);
                v.setTag(img); // <<< THIS LINE !!!!
            }
            // get the url from the data you passed to the `Map`
            // do Picasso
            // maybe you could do that by using many ways to start
            String url = (String) ((Map)getItem(position)).get("photo");
            boolean ifyoutube = url.contains("/vi/");
            com.squareup.picasso.Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
                    .borderColor(Color.BLACK)
                    .borderWidthDp(0)
                    .cornerRadiusDp(100)
                    .oval(false)
                    .build();
            if (ifyoutube) {
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
                        .load(url)
                        .fit()
                        .centerCrop()
                        .transform(transformation)
                        .into(img);
            }
            else {
                url = url.replaceAll(".jpg", "_square.jpg");
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
                        .load(url)
                        .fit()
                        .centerCrop()
                        .transform(transformation)
                        .into(img);
            }

            // return the view
            return v;
        }
    }

    public class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ContestsDetals.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String idUrl = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_ID");

            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url+idUrl);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    Log.e(TAG, "URL: " + url);
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contests = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contest");
                    //ContestsCount = jsonObj.getString("Count");
                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contests.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contests.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String type = c.getString("type");
                        title = c.getString("title");
                        String text = c.getString("text");
                        String count = c.getString("count");
                        String photo = c.getString("img");

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        JSONObject user_id = c.getJSONObject("user_id");
                        String id_user = user_id.getString("id");
                        String name = user_id.getString("name");
                        String username = user_id.getString("username");

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        JSONObject time = c.getJSONObject("time");
                        String start = time.getString("start");
                        String finish = time.getString("finish");

                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value


                        contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("type", type);
                        contact.put("title", title);
                        contact.put("text", text);
                        contact.put("count", count);
                        contact.put("id_user", id_user);
                        contact.put("name", name);
                        contact.put("username", username);
                        contact.put("start", start);
                        contact.put("finish", finish);
                        contact.put("photo", photo);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);

                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: 1");
            ListAdapter adapter =
                    new ContestsDetals.MyAdapter(
                            ContestsDetals.this, contactList,
                            R.layout.content_contests_detals,
                            new String[]{"id", "type", "title",
                                    "text", "count", "id_user", "name", "username", "start", "finish"}, new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.type,
                            R.id.title, R.id.text, R.id.count,
                            R.id.id_user, R.id.name,
                            R.id.username, R.id.start, R.id.finish});
            ListAdapter adapter2 =
                    new ContestsDetals.MyAdapter(
                            ContestsDetals.this, contactList,
                            R.layout.content_contests_detals,
                            new String[]{"id", "type", "title",
                                    "text", "count", "id_user", "name", "username", "start", "finish"}, new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.type,
                            R.id.title, R.id.text, R.id.count,
                            R.id.id_user, R.id.name,
                            R.id.username, R.id.start, R.id.finish});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_contests_detals"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.unkop.unkop.ContestsDetals">

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ERROR:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.unkop.unkop/com.unkop.unkop.ContestsDetals}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2463)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.unkop.unkop.ContestsDetals.onCreate(ContestsDetals.java:63)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5165)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1103)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Покажите 63-ю строчку из файла ContestsDetals.java.

Comment: Кстати, если приведенный xml – это `R.layout.activity_contests_detals`, то в нем нет ни одного `ListView`, однако Вы их пытаетесь там найти.

Comment: Покажите 63-ю строчку youTubeView.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);

Comment: R.layout.activity_contests_detals  - я не показал, там есть лист, а изза того, что json загрузка данных из сервера идет, то я дальше отображаю в каждом листе видео, но вот при вставке кода для видео, уже падает приложение.

Comment: В `R.layout.activity_contests_detals` есть `R.id.youtube_view`?

Comment: Вот, я снизу скинул R.layout.activity_contests_detals

Comment: Исправил, простите за незнание, пожалуйста помогите еще исправить баг с видео)

Comment: Поставьте breakpoint на строку `new ContestsDetals.GetContacts().execute();` и посмотрите чем инициализирован объект `youTubeView`: `NULL` или нет?

Comment: приложение падает после setContentView(R.layout.activity_contests_detals);

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам полегче вариант воспроизведения видео из `YouTube`:

в импорте:
`import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeStandalonePlayer;`

```
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(
    ContestsDetals.this,
    YOUTUBE_API_KEY,
    "ID видео из YouTube"
);
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
if (intent.resolveActivity(pm) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(ContestsDetals.this, "Установите приложение YouTube для просмотра видео", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

если у вас не определяется импорт, то у вас в `Gradle` не подключен файл:

`compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')`